# Oracle SQL Injection, select user from dual is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

I am learning about SQL injection. There is a regular statement that reads:

```
"select * from users where username = '" + getUsername() + "'" + " and " + "upassword = " + "'" + getPassword() + "'";
```

From what I have learnt, it is possible to perform a SQL injection attack by providing this password:

```
a' or '1' = '1
```

I will get all table entries from the database. But when I attempted to provide a user name as following:

```
' or select user from dual where '1' = '1'--
```

I got nothing in return. My understanding is with my username input as above, the regular statement would become:

```
select * from users where username = '' or select user from dual where '1' = '1'--
```

This should give me the current user. 
May I ask what has gone wrong here?

Update:

I managed to get it to work by modifying it a bit:

```
' union select * from users--
```

Now I got a whole list of username from the database.

Thanks

Comment: did you get an error?  It doesn't even look like valid SQL.

Comment: Yeah, I got an error. I am really new to SQL, this must be a silly mistake. I replaced "or" with "union", it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or select user from dual` is not a literal string rather it seems you are trying to pass in another query. If you want to pass a string literal then quote it using single quote.

Comment: @Rahul, that's the whole point. The OP is trying to simulate a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from users where username = '' or select user from dual where '1' = '1'
```

is not a valid SQL statement in Oracle. You're trying to replace the entire SELECT list with a different statement by putting into the original statement's WHERE clause, and that's just not going to work.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I actually managed to get it work by replacing "or" with "union". I see what you meant, thank you.